# Failure while starting diaspora

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, diaspora

I installed diaspora on my Ubuntu server.
Here is my stack trace. I don't know what to do to fix it.
Even couldn't find any answer via google.

```
22:45:03 web.1    | started with pid 16564
22:45:03 worker.1 | started with pid 16567
22:45:14 web.1    | /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385@diaspora/gems/unicorn-4.6.0/lib/unicorn/configurator.rb:589:in `set_path': ArgumentError (ArgumentError)
22:45:14 web.1    |     from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385@diaspora/gems/unicorn-4.6.0/lib/unicorn/configurator.rb:493:in `stderr_path'
22:45:14 web.1    |     from config/unicorn.rb:24:in `reload'
22:45:14 web.1    |     from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385@diaspora/gems/unicorn-4.6.0/lib/unicorn/configurator.rb:75:in `instance_eval'
22:45:14 web.1    |     from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385@diaspora/gems/unicorn-4.6.0/lib/unicorn/configurator.rb:75:in `reload'
22:45:14 web.1    |     from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385@diaspora/gems/unicorn-4.6.0/lib/unicorn/configurator.rb:68:in `initialize'
22:45:14 web.1    |     from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385@diaspora/gems/unicorn-4.6.0/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:108:in `new'
22:45:14 web.1    |     from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385@diaspora/gems/unicorn-4.6.0/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:108:in `initialize'
22:45:14 web.1    |     from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385@diaspora/gems/unicorn-4.6.0/bin/unicorn_rails:209:in `new'
22:45:14 web.1    |     from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385@diaspora/gems/unicorn-4.6.0/bin/unicorn_rails:209:in `<top (required)>'
22:45:14 web.1    |     from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385@diaspora/bin/unicorn_rails:19:in `load'
22:45:14 web.1    |     from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385@diaspora/bin/unicorn_rails:19:in `<main>'
22:45:14 web.1    |     from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385@diaspora/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `eval'
22:45:14 web.1    |     from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385@diaspora/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `<main>'
22:45:14 web.1    | exited with code 1
22:45:14 system   | sending SIGTERM to all processes
SIGTERM received
22:45:14 worker.1 | rake aborted!
22:45:14 worker.1 | SIGTERM
22:45:14 worker.1 | /root/diaspora_source/diaspora/config/application.rb:11:in `require'
22:45:14 worker.1 | /root/diaspora_source/diaspora/config/application.rb:11:in `<top (required)>'
22:45:14 worker.1 | /root/diaspora_source/diaspora/Rakefile:8:in `require'
22:45:14 worker.1 | /root/diaspora_source/diaspora/Rakefile:8:in `<top (required)>'
22:45:14 worker.1 | /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385@diaspora/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `eval'
22:45:14 worker.1 | /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385@diaspora/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `<main>'
22:45:14 worker.1 | (See full trace by running task with --trace)
22:45:14 worker.1 | terminated by SIGTERM
```

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As jaywink pointed out you should not run Diaspora as root.

Your error though is only happening in the currently released version and only if you set `stderr_path` and/or `stdout_path` for unicorn. It'll be fixed with this [patch](https://github.com/diaspora/diaspora/commit/43f21d6e55256b0ad161a91a39dfc702aba66574) once the next non-hotfix release is made.

Comment: Thanks a lot!! You saved hours for me :)

Answer (score 1):

Did you install Diaspora* as root? This is is absolutely not recommended, Diaspora* should be installed under a normal user.

Quote from Diaspora* installation instructions:

> We frequently see people doing everything as root. If you think that's a good idea: It's not. It's the worst thing you can do! All programs will either tell you to run them as root or ask you for the password. Do not start anything as root if it's not explicitly requested by it or this guide. Just use your normal user or create an own system user for Diaspora.

https://wiki.diasporafoundation.org/Installation

Comment: Thx for that advice! I'm relatively new at Linux :)